# Airflow - run sql procedures (SQL Server)

Tags: airflow

I am triggering the task manually from the UI and it shows the task as success but nothing happens in the database. Basically I am calling a simple procedure (with no params) that copy values from the staging table to the main and delete the contents in the staging table.

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.mssql_operator import MsSqlOperator
from datetime import datetime

dag = DAG("sql_proc_0", "Testing running of SQL procedures",
          schedule_interval = None, catchup = False,
          start_date = datetime(2019, 1, 1))

# [dbo].[LoadData] is the name of the procedure
sql_command = """ 
EXECUTE [dbo].[LoadData] 
"""

task = MsSqlOperator(task_id = 'run_test_proc', mssql_conn_id = 'mssql_azure_test',
                     sql = sql_command, dag = dag, database = 'TestDB')
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically `autocommit=False` is set by default. When it is set to `True`, it works (it took me 2 hours to figure this out and after posting it in SO!)

```
task = MsSqlOperator(task_id='run_test_proc',mssql_conn_id='mssql_azure_test',
                     sql=sql_command,dag=dag,
                     database='TestDB',
                     autocommit=True)
```

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-microsoft-mssql/stable/_api/airflow/providers/microsoft/mssql/operators/mssql/index.html